# Installing wine from source without root access

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install `wine` on my computer without root access. I know to change the prefix using `automake --prefix=$HOME/Self_Programs` but then I get this error message:

```
[tomas@wizard wine-1.1.27]$ automake --prefix=$HOME/Self_Programs`
automake: unrecognized option '--prefix=/home/tomas/Self_Programs'.`
automake: Try '/usr/bin/automake --help' for more information.`
```

(This was tried before and after using the `configure` command in the source code)

I'm really stuck here: can someone help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: @slm Umm CentOS 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a GNU autotools build system, you pass the `--prefix` option to the configure script. The following should work for compiling wine:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Self_Programs
make
make install
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for some reason. Its made everything it needs in Self_Programs but still hasn't installed.